# Ask company a question dialog stuck to top of page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

I was reading a job description, and when I got to the bottom I had a question, so I clicked the `Ask a question` button there, and this is what I saw:

[image: ask a question layout issue]

The worst part is, scrolling is disabled once the dialog opens, so I can't even scroll up to view the rest of the dialog.

My workaround for now is to only  click the button in the sidebar at the top of the page.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: If I've ever seen a company who severly needs a QA team it is stackoverflow.  Why they don't test is beyond me.

Comment: Well lets just say QUALITY ASSURANCE.  Too many reoccurring bugs on jobs that get fixed and reappear.  This is what happens when you don't test and you roll rapidly.  Thankfully they have a community who cares otherwise this place would become a desert.

Comment: @JonH Yeah, I think a QA team and/or a suite of automated tests (which AFAIK they don't have) would be helpful.

Comment: To be fair, UI issues can often be harder to catch.

Comment: @ScottWeldon - I dont know about you but, hey we just updated the jobs page with new CSS.  Can everyone open it up and click on all the things we changed.  Check - yup its good - doesn't seem that difficult to me.  Sometimes your own people become your "unit tests".

Comment: Plot twist, @JonH: everyone who participates on Meta *is* part of the Stack Overflow QA team. Also, this is why "lightboxing" effects suck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix just went out to production, thanks for spotting this.

This happened because we just got rid of jQuery UI and replaced it with alternative, lightweight modal and autocomplete libraries. FWIW we did test this pretty thoroughly but missed the case where the viewport was scrolled substantially; mostly because 99% of our modals are initiated by buttons that are visible in the viewport by default - we just didn't think to scroll down.

To address some of the comments - we have quite an extensive suite of tests (there's always room for more of course) which encapsulates /jobs and Talent but nothing for the UI (which would have picked up this error). We *used* to use Selenium but the false positive rate was too high and it just kept burning too much time investigating things which weren't actually issues.